# help with implicit value

Tags: scala, implicit

I have this bit of code, which works:

```
val directions = rs.map(_.direction) // Direction extends Enumeration
directions == directions.sorted.reverse
```

I'd like to instead do something like this:

```
ratings.map(_.direction).isInBackwardsOrder


class RichSeq[T](seq: Seq[T]) {
    def isInBackwardsOrder = seq == seq.sorted.reverse
}

object RichSeq {
    implicit def seq2richSeq[T](seq: Seq[T]) = new RichSeq[T](seq)
}
```

I keep getting the following compilation error:

```
could not find implicit value for parameter ord: Ordering[T]
def isInBackwardsOrder = seq == seq.sorted.reverse
```

What I don't understand is why it could find the implicit value for parameter ord, when it was in the original form, but cannot find it once I pull it into a utility class.

Thanks for the help,
Alex

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the original form, you had no generics. `directions` is a `Seq[SomeWellKnownType]`, and at compile time, the compiler looks for an `Ordering[SomeWellKnownType]` in implicit scope, and finds one.

On the other hand, in `RichSeq[T]`, the compiler must find an implicit `Ordering[T]` where `T` is a type parameter. No way to do that. You must ensure that the `Ordering` will be available when you create the `RichSeq` :

```
class RichSeq[T](seq: Seq[T])(implicit ev: Ordering[T]) {...
```

There is a shortcut for that, especially if you just need `ev` in implicit scope without refrencing it explicitly, as in here :

```
class RichSeq[T : Ordering](seq: Seq[T]) {...
```

Then you have the exact same problem in your implicit method, which is generic too, with the same solution :

```
implicit def seq2richSeq[T: Ordering](seq: Seq[T]) = new RichSeq[T](seq)
```

Then it should work. The `seq2richSeq` implicit conversion will kick in when an Ordering is available for the type of the elements in the Seq.

Comment: I still had the same problem when I changed it to [T: Ordering], earlier

Comment: This works. Behind the scenes, assuming the enumeration type is `Direction`, the compiler looks for an `Ordering[Direction.Value]` which is not a well known type, but using the implicit `Ordering.ordered[A]` it summons one as needed. So the resulting code after typer phase looks like `seq2richSeq(directions)(Ordering.ordered[Direction.Value](Predef.conforms[Direction.Value])).isInBackwardsOrder`. Amazing...

Comment: Indeed, getting the Ordering from Ordered (with conforms on the top of it) is in my view the most impressive part. That part is already at works in the non generic version though.

Comment: Don't have time to check now.  Maybe I was doing something slighly different. Thanks for your help

Comment: I think I was using [T: Ordered], when it should have been [T: Ordering]  Thanks for your help with this!

Comment: Just made the change to Ordering.  It worked like a charm. Thanks.